# How to setup a older meteor version in dockerfile, and docker container

Tags: docker, meteor, dockerfile

I have a project running with meteor and node.js in my local. The meteor version is 2.4, node.js version is 8.9.4, I have meteor/release file to make meteor version be 2.2 so that meteor and node can work together.

```
(base) xxx$ meteor --version
Meteor 2.4
(base) xxx$ node -v
v8.9.4
```

[image]

It seems fine so I deploy this project to docker container to server. The Dockerfile first line I wrote

```
# node version dependent on meteor version
FROM node:8.9.4
```

After successfully deployed, the docker logs shows error siad.

```
Waiting for mongodb server to start - sleeping
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: /app/bundle/main.js
error:   undefined
data:    /app/bundle/main.js:34 - Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later.
data:    /app/bundle/main.js:34 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

I check inside docker, the node version is 8.9.4

```
(base) [xxx]$  docker exec -it -u root tblbuilder_meteor_1 /bin/bash -c 'node --version'
v8.9.4
```

So I assume it is meteor version. But first I dont know how to check meteor version inside the docker. And second why this happens? I am sure the release file is updated to push project folder.

With some great man help, I kinda understand it. In local I use meteor 2.2, in docker file I use node.js 8.9.4 work with meteor2.2. So the thing I left is to modify DOCKERFILE, change it from node 8.9.4 to node 12.  Below is my Dockerfile file, I try to change it to node 12.22.2, but it keep give me error, I spent one day to solve them. Currently, I stack at install r-base part.
Is there some guide for change node 8 to node 12.

```
# node version dependent on meteor version
FROM node:8.9.4
# I am going to use 12.22.2
#FROM node:12.22.2

# (even if copied as root you still need to change)
# https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6119
COPY ./compose/meteor/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./compose/meteor/run_app.sh /run_app.sh
COPY ./compose/meteor/r-cran.pgp /r-cran.pgp
COPY ./settings/settings.json /app/settings.json
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
COPY ./r_requirements.sh /r_requirements.sh

# set locale to utf8: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/703/files
# added [check-valid-until=no] & Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false"; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository
# Needs work to bring it up-to-date
RUN \
    echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list && \
    sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update && \
    \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list' && \
    apt-key add /r-cran.pgp && \
    \
    apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update && \
    apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false install -y locales && \
    \
    localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 && \
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && \
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && \
    export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.utf8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# add rstudio debian install for R (requires version >3.3)
# https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/
# install R from apt-get
# install python 3.6 from source :/

RUN apt install -y --force-yes r-base-core r-recommended r-base-html r-base-core

RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes wget bsdtar r-base r-base-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz && \
    tar zxf Python-3.6.5.tgz && \
    cd ./Python-3.6.5 && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make altinstall && \
    cd .. && \
    rm Python-3.6.5.tgz && \
    rm -rf ./Python-3.6.5

# create paths and users
# change executable permissions
RUN npm install forever -g && \
    \
    mkdir -p /app/production && \
    mkdir -p /app/logs && \
    mkdir -p /app/crons && \
    \
    groupadd -r app && \
    useradd -m -d /home/app -g app app && \
    \
    chmod +x /entrypoint.sh && \
    chmod +x /run_app.sh && \
    chmod +x /r_requirements.sh && \
    chmod +x /requirements.txt && \

    \
    chown -R app:app /app && \
    chown app:app /entrypoint.sh && \
    chown app:app /run_app.sh && \
    chown app:app /r_requirements.sh &&\
    chown app:app /requirements.txt

USER app

# 1) install R packages
# 2) install python packages
RUN export "R_LIBS=/home/app/R_libs" && \
    mkdir /home/app/R_libs && \
    bash /r_requirements.sh && \
    \
    /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 install --user -r /requirements.txt

USER root
COPY ./compose/meteor/src/src.tar.gz /app/src.tar.gz
COPY ./src/private /app/src/private
RUN chown -R app:app /app

USER app
RUN cd /app && \
    bsdtar -xzvf src.tar.gz && \
    npm install --prefix /app/bundle/programs/server --production

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many wrong understanding in your tests:

1. Your Meteor version is 2.2, because is the version inside your project;
2. To you see the Node version of this Meteor project, see this answers that many guys send to you in [Meteor Docker Node.js version is not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502882/meteor-docker-node-js-version-is-not-match/69508062)
3. Usually, we build the Meteor, that mean transform it in a NodeJS package build, then, inside of the Docker you don't need Meteor.
4. We need see your Dockerfile and understand what process you do to build do Docker image.

Comment: Thank you man. I kinda understand now. In local I use meteor 2.2, nothing with node.js. When I deploy, I use node.js 8.9.4 because I wrote it in dockerfile. Meteor 2.2 wants node 12 or above. So my problem is to modify dockerfile. But I tried one whole day, still did not pass all. mostly stack at install r-base part.

Comment: @ZicongWang, show me your Dockerfile.

Comment: if you can see, I added it to my post. End of my post.

Comment: I looked your Dockerfile. I understood that you put many apps in the same docker image, right? I thought this is not a good idea, exactly because this problem you had now with different node version.

Comment: When you use Docker, when possible, the best practice is have different services in different dockers. Thus, you can update each one without impact the other. I understand that now is hard to you, but I think is the best way, split in more containers.